# Aplicar fragmento de código a ciertos productos en Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin

Cuento con un sitio en Wordpress con Woocommerce y tengo un código que redondea mis precios finales en el carrito:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'custom_calculated_total' );

    function custom_calculated_total( $total ) {

      $total = round( $total, -2 );

      return $total;

    }
```

Este código funciona perfectamente en todo mi sitio, pero **necesito desactivarlo para CIERTO producto en particular,** ya que tiene un costo de $750 y el código, como es ahora, me lo redondea a $800

Honestamente no cuento con experiencia en PHP y me está costando encontrar una forma de solucionar esto.

Comment: el signature del [filtro tiene 2 parametros](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/9db2c452905ebf796a8e8b4d63db64b57e169dbe/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart-totals.php#L877) el segundo sería el carrito (cart)  con ese [cart](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-get-cart-info-total-items-etc-from-cart-object/) podes obtener los items

Comment: Hola, alo Malbarez, gracias por tu respuesta, pero creo que no entiendo cómo aplicar esto :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ver que y cuantos parámetros soporta un filtro es conveniente [buscar en el repo de woocommerce](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?q=woocommerce_calculated_total), lo vas a ver donde se aplica como `apply_filters( nombre_de_filter, param1, param2, etc...)`. (*) Si es un action lo vas a ver como `do_action( ...`

[image: buscando actions y filters en el source]

Para exponer mas parametros a tu versión del filtro se agrega el número de parametros en el [`add_filter`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/).

```
add_filter(
  'woocommerce_calculated_total',
  'custom_calculated_total',
  10, 2  // <- prioridad en el stack, número de parámetros
);

function custom_calculated_total( $total, $cart ) {

  foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
    if ( 9878 == $product_id ){
      // hacer algo diferente para el prod id 9878 dentro de un cart
    }
  }

  $total = round( $total, -2 );
  return $total;
}
```

De los ejemplos que vas a ver en la web `WC()->cart` sería equivalente a `$cart` en el contexto del filtro. Así que tomando [el código del enlace](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-get-cart-info-total-items-etc-from-cart-object/) quedaría algo así:

```php
// Loop over $cart items
foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
   $product = $cart_item['data'];
   $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
   $variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id'];
   $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
   $price = $cart->get_product_price( $product );
   $subtotal = $cart->get_product_subtotal( $product, $cart_item['quantity'] );
   $link = $product->get_permalink( $cart_item );
   // Anything related to $product, check $product tutorial
   $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
   $whatever_attribute = $product->get_attribute( 'whatever' );
   $whatever_attribute_tax = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_whatever' );
   $any_attribute = $cart_item['variation']['attribute_whatever'];
   $meta = wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item );
}
```

Si son varios los productos "especiales" tal vez convenga agregarle un metadata o attributo al producto o variación así no tenes que hardcodear los ID. El testeo dentro del foreach que daría algo así:

```
    if ( 'NO' === $product->get_attribute( 'redondear_totales' ) ) {
      // no modifica $total
    } else {
      $total = round( $total, -2 );
    }
  }
  return $total;
```

Comment: Hola, alo, Malbarez! Te agradezco infinitamente por esta respuesta, super clara y me solucionó el problema!

Comment: fijate si de [romper](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.break.php) el foreach al encontrar el producto o poner un "guard" ( un encontrado = true/false )  por fuera asi no `round`eas por cada item cuando son muchos o si el mismo producto puede ser agregado varias veces. eso dependerá de cómo se haya implementado el carrito o tienda ( one page checkout, suscriptions, etc..)